# Displaying name from an inner joined table?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got two tables, one called category, which has the rows id and name, and another called placecategory, which has the tables id, place_id and category_id. I need to inner join these two to echo out the names of the categories where the placecategory.place_id is equal to a $GET[ID].

I've got this so far, but it echo's out nothing.

```
<?php 
include('includes/connectdb.php');

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['id']);

$qry = 'SELECT id, name FROM category
INNER JOIN placecategory
ON category.id = placecategory.category_id
WHERE placecategory.place_id = '.$id.'';

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$qry);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

 echo ''.$row['name'].'';
        };
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the error log? Do you have `error_reporting` turned on?

Comment: I tried displaying errors and I'm getting this error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ----------------- on line 58

Comment: Line 58 is equivalent to the line where the while loop starts

Comment: Try mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: Gives me the same error; Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean ..... on line 58 :/

Comment: Quite simply your query has failed and therefore this line `$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$qry);` has returned `false` instead of a `mysqli_result` object. Fix the query You are supposed to test `$result` after a `mysqli_query($dbc,$qry);` call before continuing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wont fix your query, but it will display the error generated by the incorrect query. Its a start.

I cannot solve the query issue without a better understanding of your schema.

```
<?php 
include('includes/connectdb.php');

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['id']);

$qry = 'SELECT id, name 
        FROM category
           INNER JOIN placecategory ON category.id = placecategory.category_id
        WHERE placecategory.place_id = '.$id;

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$qry);

// test the status before continuing    
if ( ! $result ) {
    echo mysqli_error($dbc);
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I get this message with your code: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in ....... on line 60, which is "echo mysqli_error();"

Comment: It says "Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: I specified the table name in the select query and it worked. --> 'SELECT category.id, category.name AS name....